# LINQ should return no records if where contains empty string

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, linq-to-sql

I am trying to fetch the car records where car description filter text. But I should not return any records if the filter text is empty. The following code is working but is there a better way to do this avoiding cars.where(c => false)

```
public JsonResult GetCars(string cFilter)
{
    IQueryable<Cars> cars = CarService.GetCars();
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(cFilter))
        cars = cars.Where(c => c.carDescr.Contains(cFilter));
    else
        cars = cars.Where(c => false);
    var carInfo = (from c in cars
                      select (new { id = c.CarID, description = c.CarID + "-" + c.carDescr })).ToList();
    return Json(carInfo, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could skip out the use of CarService entirely.

```
public JsonResult GetCars(string cFilter)
{
  IQueryable<Cars> cars;
  if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(cFilter))
    cars = CarService.GetCars().Where(c => c.carDescr.Contains(cFilter));
  else
    cars = Enumerable.Empty<Cars>().AsQueryable();

  var carInfo = (from c in cars
                 select (new { id = c.CarID, description = c.CarID + "-" + c.carDescr })).ToList();
  return Json(carInfo, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

You could cache the `EnumerableQuery<Cars>` produced by `Enumreable.Empty<Cars>()` or indeed just return a `JsonResult` for an empty array in any case, since any empty json array is an empty json array:

```
public JsonResult GetCars(string cFilter)
{
  if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(cFilter))
    return Json(Enumerable.Empty<object>(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

    var carInfo = (from c in CarService.GetCars()
                      where c.carDescr.Contains(cFilter)
                      select (new { id = c.CarID, description = c.CarID + "-" + c.carDescr })).ToList();
    return Json(carInfo, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

I'd go for this latter, but it's worth mentioning the former for cases where it is the only of the two that is applicable.

Comment: Thanks for the nice two approaches @Jon

Answer (score 0):

I dont know i missed something but you set `null` only for `cFilter` is `null`

```
public JsonResult GetCars(string cFilter)
{

    IQueryable<Cars> cars = CarService.GetCars();
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(cFilter))
     {cars = cars.Where(c => c.carDescr.Contains(cFilter));
       var carInfo = (from c in cars
                     select (new { id = c.CarID, description = c.CarID + "-" + c.carDescr })).ToList();
      return Json(carInfo, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
     }   
    else
       {

         return Json("", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
       } 


}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am getting this error in the next line **[ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null**

Comment: **carInfo** does not exist in the current context.

Comment: this is simple error check edit again please just var carInfo defined at top @vineel

Comment: I know it seems simple but it is killing me :) Now with the new changes I get this error ** cannot assign <null> to an implicitly-typed local variable **

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106031/discussion-between-vineel-and-alper-tunga-arslan).

Answer (score 0):

Got another solution. Added cFilter empty or null check in the where clause and it worked.

```
cars = cars.Where(c => c.carDescr.Contains(cFilter) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(cFilter));
```

Complete function below.

```
public JsonResult GetCars(string cFilter)
        {
            IQueryable<Cars> cars = CarService.GetCars();
            cars = cars.Where(c => c.carDescr.Contains(cFilter) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(cFilter));
            var carInfo = (from c in cars
                           select (new { id = c.CarID, description = c.CarID + "-" + c.carDescr })).ToList();
            return Json(carInfo, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```